# Find all uses of a method in vim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim

Is there a way to find all uses of a method in vim? I'm using vim as an IDE for Rails with rails.vim. ctags helps to jump to a method definition from usage but not the other way round AFAIK. I'd like to be able to find everywhere (controllers, views etc) that a method has been used.

Comment: perhaps this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42079881

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There aren't any perfect solutions for this in Vim, but you can get close with [`cscope`](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/) and `grep` or `ack`.

`cscope` will help you find all references to a symbol.  It's made for C and C-like languages, but it does a decent job of matching symbols in Ruby code as well.  It's not going to get the context right all the time.

Here's a [vim cscope tutorial](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_vim_tutorial.html) and a [blog post about Ruby/Vim/cscope](http://www.cuberick.com/2008/11/navigating-larger-ruby-codebases-with.html), and [another blog post](http://stolowski.blogspot.com/2011/07/finding-your-way-in-vim.html), both of which include additional tips about navigating Ruby/Rails code in Vim.

Using `grep` or `ack` from Vim with quickfix integration is another great way to find symbols.  They've got no notion of scope/context, but often a simple search is enough.  Using just the built-in `:grep` command, you can do:

```
:grep some_method app/controllers
:cwindow
```

And get the results of the search in the quickfix window, which will allow you to quickly navigate to the matching files and line numbers.

A much better option is the [ack.vim](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim) plugin, which integrates [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) with Vim and makes use of the quickfix window.

If you're not already using a plugin for navigating CTAGS, I recommend [Tagbar](http://majutsushi.github.com/tagbar/).

Comment: Excellent. I will definitely try these out. grep, of course, is an old standby but I used to use it stand-alone (on another terminal window). Integrated into my main editor even without a lot of context would be a lot better.

Comment: I'm working on my own config for dealing with cscope in my Rails projects.  Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/fweep/5182260) with some of it.  Note that it's only some of my config, and is tightly coupled with my Git setup, but I think it might help you get started if you want to jump in with cscope; there's enough information there to create a `cscope.out` database and load/search it in Vim.  You'll probably want to change some of the path names.  If I make it into a plugin and/or write a blog post about it, I'll comment here.

Answer (score 7):

I wrote a gem to do just that: https://rubygems.org/gems/starscope

It parses ruby code properly and exports to ctags and cscope file formats.

Comment: I'll definitely check it out!

Comment: Sure, I will do that shortly. I didn't even realize it wouldn't work with versions that old.

Comment: I just released a new version (0.1.10) which works on Ruby 1.9.2 so you should be able to try it now.