# How to move upward at the end of the tag list in vim?

Tags: vim, ctags, cscope

[image: My VIM screenshot]

When I search symbol by tag and reach the end of the tag lists, I can not move upward again. So whenever I want to find the previous symbols, I have to hit the tag search again. It bothers me a lot especially when long-time work needed (ex. find greping symobol by cscope).

Does anybody know how to move upward at the end of the tag lists in vim search?

Comment: What command did you do to get that list? Also, `:help :tselect`.

Comment: It's gtags-cscope, "cs find e poll_lock".

Comment: You might want to add crucial informations like this to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `:tp` or `:tprev`?

```
:ts or :tselect shows the list
:tn or :tnext goes to the next tag in that list
:tp or :tprev goes to the previous tag in that list
:tf or :tfirst goes to the first tag of the list
:tl or :tlast goes to the last tag of the list
```

I found the reference here at this site: https://andrew.stwrt.ca/posts/vim-ctags/

Comment: I think those commands are for command line mode. What I want is for moving in tag list buffer. In the buffer, :tfirst command is not working.